# Using $(this) within .get is undefined in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scope

I'm using the shorthand AJAX call, `$.get` but when I try and reference a variable with `$(this)`, jQuery tells me that it's undefined.

Here is the block of code:

```
$('.replaceWithObject').live('click', function(event) {
    var cid = $(this).find('input').val();
    $.get('GetVideoComment.ashx?cid=' + cid, function(data) {
        $(this).html(data);
    });
});
```

It finds the `cid` just fine, as `$(this)` is available prior to the `$.get`.  Inside the `.get` `$(this)` is undefined.  Setting a var to `$(this)` prior to the `get` doesn't work either?

`getVideoComment.ashx?cid=628` works, it returns a flash object.  The issue is that `$(this)` is undefined inside the `get`.

Any idea on how to do what I want to do here?  Or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cache your initial select so it exists when your callback fires.

```
$('.replaceWithObject').live('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cid = $this.find('input').val();
    $.get('GetVideoComment.ashx?cid=' + cid, function(data) {
        $this.html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.replaceWithObject').live('click', function(event) {
    var that = $(this);
    var cid = that.find('input').val();
    $.get('GetVideoComment.ashx', {'cid': cid}, function(data) {
        that.html(data);
    });
});
```

The problem is that `this` inside of the `get` function all is no longer `.replaceWithObject`
If you cache the this on the click event and use that cache then it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

As the returned data seems to be HTML, you could also just use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

```
$('.replaceWithObject').live('click', function(event) {
    var cid = $(this).find('input').val();
    $(this).load('GetVideoComment.ashx?cid=' + cid);
    // or $(this).load('GetVideoComment.ashx', {cid: cid});
});
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  This works, and makes more sense. But I didn't understand why I was outside the scope of this inside the get...  Still don't actually. =(

Comment: @Blankasaurus: `this` is a special variable and is set to the object, a method is invoked on. You are not calling `get()` on an element but on the `jQuery` object. So inside the callback `this` cannot be set to the element, because it does not know anything about it.